# error C2593: 'operator ==' is ambiguous

Tags: visual-studio

im just not following what the problem is, i receive this error message:

```
error C2593: 'operator ==' is ambiguous
```

when using this line of code in my project, this source compiled fine in VC6 but in my VC2010 i get the error message that wont allow compile. The source is below.

```
if( m_cardThreePlace == 0 ) {
    // generate player cards
    OnCardGenerate( 3 );

    OnWhatPlayerCardsActive( 3 );
    // set card for placement
    m_cardThreePlace = m_cardPlaceTemp;
    // clear placement temp
    m_cardPlaceTemp = _T("");
}
```

the declaration looks like this:

```
CString m_cardThreePlace;    

m_cardThreePlace = _T("");
```

the output window shows this:

BlackJack.cpp(239): error C2593: 'operator ==' is ambiguous
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\cstringt.h(2551): could be 'bool ATL::CStringT::operator ==(const ATL::CStringT &,char) throw()' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
          with
          [
              BaseType=char,
              StringTraits=StrTraitMFC
          ]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\cstringt.h(2400): or       'bool ATL::CStringT::operator ==(const ATL::CStringT &,const wchar_t *) throw(...)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
          with
          [
              BaseType=char,
              StringTraits=StrTraitMFC
          ]
          C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\cstringt.h(2385): or       'bool ATL::CStringT::operator ==(const ATL::CStringT &,const char *) throw()' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
          with
          [
              BaseType=char,
              StringTraits=StrTraitMFC
          ]
          while trying to match the argument list '(CString, int)'

Comment: what does the declaration of m_cardThreePlace look like?

Comment: Is there anything in your output window? This should show the full compile log, including some information relating to the error.

Answer (score 1):

The literal reason you're getting a compiler error is because `CString` provides three applicable overloads of the `==` operator: one for comparing to a single `char`, and two for comparing to C-style strings of the `char*` and `wchar_t*` varieties. Literal `0` could covert to any of these types, so the compiler isn't able to unambiguously figure out which you meant.

Now, the meaningful reason you're getting an error here is because `==` is intended to compare *strings* and you're trying to compare to a *number*. I'm guessing that you're trying to see if `m_cardThreePlace` is the empty string. If that's what you're going for, you can simply write:

```
if( m_cardThreePlace.IsEmpty() )
```

It's good that your code no longer compiles, as it's apparent that what you *wrote* and what you *meant* are two different things.

Comment: @Dave: Glad this worked for you. If you have more questions in the future, post them! That's what SO is for. Just as a reminder, if an answer is correct for your question, it's proper etiquette to [mark it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). This helps others who have the same question quickly see the solution (and helps out the answerer as well).